# Object-oriented programming style

Tags: c++, oop, fstream

I am studying OOP in C++ but the programming style made me crazy. Which style is OOP for a function input from file. Thanks!

```
class Point{
public:
   Point();
   ~Point();
   //<input from file>
private:
   int x, y;
}
```

Style 1:

```
void Input(char* file_name){
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open(file_name);
   //<read the file>
   fin.close();
}
```

Style 2:

```
void Input(ifstream &fin){
   //<read the file>
}
```

Comment: both are not.. it should be void Point::Input(char* file_name);

Comment: @lakesh But a point class shouldn't care about input files.

Comment: @lakesh I mean which coding style can be replaced at <input frome file> line. So you said Style 1 is for OOP?

Comment: @juanchopanza this is an example

Comment: Style 2 is not so bad, but if you can pass an `istream&` (no `f` there) instead, it would be "better OOP", since it would make use of polymorphism.

Comment: If you are going for the filename approach, pass `const char *`

Answer (score 3):

Point should not care about files specifically. It can provide stream operators to input/output into any stream type.

```
class Point{
public:
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

   friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Point& point)
   {
        return is >> point.x >> point.y;
   }

   friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Point& point)
   {
        return os << point.x << " " << point.y << " ";
   }

private:
   int x, y;
}

ifstream file("file.txt");
Point p;
file >> p;
```